# H(s) in closed loop transfer function incorrect?

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system, transfer-function

I need some help verifying the transfer function of this amplifier circuit stage. The below circuit has a gain of 20 from the result of Rf and Rg.

[image]
Below is the nodal analysis equation where G is used to show conductance.
[image]

The problem I am having is that I have 2 transfer functions in a feedback loop. G(s) and H(s), the op amp open loop transfer function and the closed loop transfer function. When they combine in feedback loop I get a final transfer function of G(s)/(1+G(s)*H(s))

**My output transfer function however seems to have gain bode plot of less than unity!**

- Green curve = output transfer function
- Blue curve = G(s) op amp open loop transfer function
- Orange curve = close loop H(s)

**Shouldn't the amplifier stage, well, amplify?**  I can clearly see that the math works out to make it less than unity gain, but how is the output voltage going to be amplified?
For example: at DC the math works out to be -26dB, gain of ~1/20. Similarly, the closed loop gain is around +26dB.

When applying H(s) to G(s), in feedback it became net negative.  But to apply a real voltage at the input and expect an output, let's say for 1 volt input @DC, Vi=1,  Vo=Vi*TF -> Vo=1*0.05011=0.05011.

The problem here is I am missing 1/x somewhere to get the proper gain of 20. I thought the transfer function is Vo=TF*Vi not Vo=1/TF *Vi?

[image]

Comment: What gain & phase do you want at all critical frequencies?  Must define!this is trivial on Falstad’s Bode Plotter but you can compute easier with Admittance for parallel feedback  to 1/Rg for gain so compute 1/Av(f) the Y(f) for each part attenuates the inverse gain.

Comment: as the net phase shifts past 90 deg it starts towards positive feedback and boosts the breakpoint gain of Green

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. I want a gain of 20 at most frequencies. My phase just has to be enough so that it isn't ringy-dingy. Why would the green curve (output transfer function) be under unity gain? The amplifier transfer function should amplify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Mathematica.

Your system

[image: feedback system with G and H]

G should be of the format \$\frac{V3}{V1}\$. i.e. V1 is input, V3 is output of G(s)

H should be of the format \$\frac{V1}{V3}\$. i.e. **V3 is input** and **V1 is output** of H(s).

However, your image seems to show that `HofS1` is a function which takes V1 as input and produces V3 as output. I think that this actually represents `1/H(s)`.

So the line `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect(..)` is actually doing

\$\frac{G(s)}{1 + G(s)\frac{1}{H(s)}} = \frac{G(s)H(s)}{H(s) + G(s)} \$

So for large values of G(s) (below 10^7 Hz?) you may be effectively plotting H(s) which is supported by the observation that green plot and yellow plot are symmetric about 0 dB.

Comment: This answer is trying to answer "*The problem here is I am missing 1/x somewhere to get the proper gain of 20*". I don't know Mathematica, so I cannot check.

Comment: This is the answer! I fixed this and it worked thanks again @AJN!

Answer (score 0):

Use a PID (or a PI controller rather:

[image]

Source: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Chapter-Ten-Pid-Control-10.1-Basic-Control/32f76117181bcdd012511fdc0d78c96378a46e72 Figure 10

The P is the gain term, you want this to be 20.

\$ K_p = 20 = \frac{R_2}{R_1}\$

The I term will be where you want the pole to be (you only get one with the PI controller with a -20db/dec rolloff)

\$ K_I = 2\pi f  = R_2 C_2 \$

If you really do need the output non-inverted, then use another inverting stage with a gain of 1 after the first one.

Comment: Thanks,  the circuit topology is one part of an instrumentation amplifier so it needs to be noninverting. I am just not sure why the transfer function curve is below unity gain when it does amplify in a SPICE program.

Comment: If both sides of the instrumentation amplifier are not balanced it will destroy your common mode voltage range

Comment: I think I need to swap solving for V3/V1 and solve for V1/V3 since input is actually output in a feedback system!

Comment: Why are you using an inst amp for this?

Comment: I was encountering stability problems in an existing in-amp circuit. Doing the control theory analysis was my next step in order to improve gain margin

Comment: what do you have the other terminal of the inst amp connected to?